# How to get the global max value from a list of matrices containing NA values?

Tags: r

How to get the global max value if the matrices contain NA values? I tried with the given solution at

[R: Getting maximum value from all matrices in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663145/r-getting-maximum-value-from-all-matrices-in-a-list)

`max(unlist(lapply(mylist,FUN=max)))`

but the output is showing NA. Also tried with

`max(unlist(lapply(na.omit(mylist),FUN=max)))`

but still the output is NA.

To Reproduce:

```
m1 <- cbind(c(1,NA,3),c(7,2,4))
m2 <- cbind(c(-1,19,13),c(21,NA,5),c(3,3,0),c(4,5,6))
m3 <- cbind(c(1,2,3,NA,5),c(8,18,4,6,7))
mylist <- list(M1=m1,M2=m2,M3=m3)
```

Comment: `max(unlist(lapply(mylist, FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Could you able to post in answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `na.rm=TRUE` in the `lapply` statement:

```
max(unlist(lapply(mylist, FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

or explicitly in the `FUN` argument:

```
max(unlist(lapply(mylist, FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE))))
```