# Getting maximum value for specific matrix element over multiple matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, max, element

I have many matrixes (20 rows/20 cols). I want to find the maximum for a specific element (cell) over all those matrixes, e.g. row 9 column 17.

This is getting close to it:
[R: Getting maximum value from all matrices in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663145/r-getting-maximum-value-from-all-matrices-in-a-list)
but I couldnt manage to rewrite it to my needs. Right now I have my matrixes in a list.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If it is not the example in the link, you may need to show some example and expected result based on that example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr)

mats <- llply(1:1000, function(x) replicate(20, rnorm(20)))

getEntry <- function(mat, row, col) {

  mat[row, col]

}

getMax <- function(mats, row, col) {

  max(laply(mats, function(x) getEntry(x, row, col)))

}

# Get max of row 2, col 3 & row 12, col 19
getMax(mats, 2, 3)
getMax(mats, 12, 19)
```

This should do what you're asking. It extracts the cell specified from each matrix and then takes the max of all the options.

Comment: `llply/laply` are from `plyr`.  You need to mention the `library(plyr)`.  Also, this could be done with `base R` functions `sapply/lapply` etc.  I posted an answer without knowing that a answer was already posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a base solution (using the sample data in akrun's deleted answer) but not actually needing an anonymous function:

```
 set.seed(24)
 lst <- lapply(1:4, function(i) matrix(sample(0:9, 20*20,
         replace=TRUE), ncol=20))
 str(lst)

List of 4
 $ : int [1:20, 1:20] 2 2 7 5 6 9 2 7 8 2 ...
 $ : int [1:20, 1:20] 4 1 1 8 9 5 7 0 1 6 ...
 $ : int [1:20, 1:20] 1 8 3 1 2 6 2 3 7 5 ...
 $ : int [1:20, 1:20] 2 3 5 4 3 2 7 2 1 5 ...


 max( sapply(lst, "[", i=9, j=7) )  # Use `[` as a function with 3 parameters:
                                      #  object and 2 indices
[1] 8
```

Comment: This works too. I considered doing it sans anonymous function but decided to include it for readability.

Comment: Similar: `library(abind); arr <- do.call(abind,c(lst,list(along=3))); max(arr[i,j,])` Might be handy to have an array instead of a list anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(pmax,lst)[i,j]
```

This works, unless I've misunderstood the question. It might be wasteful to take the max for all elements in this way, but I doubt it's a big deal.